# What is the issue with this reverse array code in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

The program compile fine, but crashes when is running and shows this : 
Process terminated with status -1073741819

```
void reverse(char *str){

    char * end1 = str;
    char tmp = 'c';
    if(str){
        while(*end1){
            ++end1;
        }
        --end1;

        while(str<end1){
            tmp=*str;
            *str=*end1;
            *end1=tmp;
            str++;
            end1--;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you calling `reverse`? Are you sure that the string you're passing is modifiable? I.e. *not* `char* str = "foo";`.

Comment: Guessing a string literal.

Comment: Yeah this function looks fine as is.  You are likely calling it on illegal input.

Comment: not sure but have you used `using namespace std;` ? This might have  collission with `std::endl` and `char* endl`

Comment: @Jagannath Nah, his is `end1` not `endl` and even if it was, it would mask it due to being a locally declared variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your `reverse` implementation: your code will work as long as the string that you pass is null-terminated and writable.

Then there must be something wrong with the way that you invoke it. The most common possibility is passing a string literal, writing to which is undefined behavior that may cause a crash:

```
char *s = "quick brown fox";
reverse(s); // <<== This would be undefined behavior
```

[Demo of your working code](http://ideone.com/KlpO1t).

Comment: Thanks , i wasn't paying attention to the way i called the function.